# How does a router identify a device with a static ip?

Tags: networking, router, arp

When a static ip is configured on a device, how does a device identifies itself to the router or how does a router identify the device? What process/protocol involved here?

I belive it has something to do with Address Resolution Protocol and ARP tables, but from my knowledge ARP is used to discover the MAC address of a node with a certain IP address.

Comment: *"but from my knowledge ARP is used to discover the MAC address of a node with a certain IP address"* – if it's not that, then what else do you mean by identifying a device?

Comment: While in many home networks the same physical device plays the role of both router and DHCP server, they are still two different logical parts of the network. The router doesn't hand out IPs and so has no reason to treat and static and dynamic addressed device differently. The DHCP server is the device that "cares" about this on a network, and so long as the static IP isn't conflicting with a dynamic IP already assigned, there won't be a problem.

Comment: @user1686 My question is simply this: when a device is assigned with static configuration, how does it tell Router / DHCP Server “Hey I’m assigned with IP address #.#.#.#, don't assign it to other devices (DHCP) and forward traffic with my destination address to me.

Comment: I think even if someone has an IP assigned by DHCP you cannot prevent someone else from using this IP as static IP too. Also someone else could use your MAC address or IPv6 address so there is a collision. That's how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when a device is assigned with static configuration, how does it tell Router / DHCP Server “Hey I’m assigned with IP address #.#.#.#, don't assign it to other devices (DHCP)

It doesn't.

Some DHCP servers try to avoid conflicts by actively probing via ARP for the address before issuing a lease, but that's optional and you *can* get a duplicate address issued.

(Because of that, often the DHCP address pool is deliberately selected to be smaller than the entire subnet, to reserve some space for static assignments. Another option is for the DHCP server's admin to manually add "static leases" or "reservations" for the individual devices.)

Sometimes hosts themselves will probe for duplicates via ARP before they start using an address (e.g. Windows does this even for statically configured addresses); in IPv4 this is still optional, but in IPv6 such "Duplicate Address Detection" becomes mandatory.

> and forward traffic with my destination address to me.

Assuming the address is still within the local subnet: The router makes an ARP query for the destination address and forwards packets to the MAC address that was resolved through ARP.

(The same mechanism is also used when hosts send packets to/through a router, or when hosts send directly to other hosts within the subnet, i.e. it's symmetric and there's no real distinction between "host" vs "router".)

Note that DHCP leases are *not* used to forward packets even if the address was issued via DHCP – all packet forwarding relies on ARP (or the IPv6 equivalent NDP). Often, the DHCP server may even be hosted on a separate device from the router.

---

(On the other hand, *prefix* delegation in IPv6 – i.e. when a customer router claims an entire subnet range from its upstream ISP router – does rely on DHCPv6 to update the upstream's routing table.)

Comment: The things became clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The router generally does not care if a device has a static IP. A device IP looks exactly the same to a router whether Dynamic or Static.

The exception perhaps is the ability for some router to provide DHCP Reservation.

In this case the router has a table of MAC address and IP address to go with that MAC address. So my main workstation is set up DHCP but always gets the IP address in the Reservation table.

Once assigned, the IP address looks exactly the same to the router as any other IP address.

I use DHCP Reservation and the Device IP address is actually DHCP even though the router always assigns the same address to the device.

In a router, the LAN address range normally occurs with a DHCP range and a non-DHCP range.  Depending on the device, addresses may part of either range (not both). But the router does not itself see any difference in the IP address used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but seeing all the answers here, I think my question was misunderstood. I'm well aware of DHCP reservations and that a router basically works the same with static and dynamic addresses. My question is simply this: when a device is assigned with static configuration, how does it tell Router / DHCP Server “Hey I’m assigned with IP address #.#.#.#, don't assign it to other devices (DHCP) and forward traffic with my destination address to me.

Comment: For a standard device and a standard router, a router does not know and does not care if the address of the device was set up Dynamic (DHCP) or Static. The IP addresses look the same. For internal LAN forwarding MAC addresses are used (assuming I understand your question correctly)

Answer (score 0):

ARP converts an IP address to a link layer address.

- Very often these days this will be a MAC address for Ethernet, but many other ["hardware types"](https://www.iana.org/assignments/arp-parameters/arp-parameters.xhtml) are supported.
- This is needed because the link layer is only concerned with things that are on the same link (switch, Wi-Fi channel, etc.).

  - To send to things not on the same link, a router must be on that link and your system has to send traffic to it instead of directly to the other party.

Things about ARP:

- ARP - and the link layer really - do not care about the IP address at all or where it came from - whether that was statically assigned, via DHCP, or via APIPA.
- ARP is to be used in a situation where the hardware supports broadcasting.

  - This is done on Ethernet by sending to MAC address FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.  Broadcast frames are received by all NICs on the link.
  - So ARP doesn't need the IP address to reach all systems on a link.

If your device has a static IP and other system X needs to know its MAC address, X will issue an ARP request using the broadcast MAC, and the system with that IP will respond.

(If this sounds insecure, it is, and is the basis of more than a few network attacks and a reason why VLANs are used to keep devices separated on business networks)

Comment: The link is missing

Comment: I've gone ahead and fixed it. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but seeing all the answers here, I think my question was misunderstood. My question is simply this: when a device is assigned with static configuration, how does it tell Router / DHCP Server “Hey I’m assigned with IP address #.#.#.#, don't assign it to other devices (DHCP) and forward traffic with my destination address to me.